# How to barre this chord without muting adjacent string?

Tags: guitar, fingering

[image]

I found this online.
How do you barre with the third(ring) finger without it touching and muting the G string? Anatomically speaking it's really hard for my ring finger to not touch the G string while barring the A and D string, not matter how I adjust

Answer (score 2):

I'm amazed! A chord on the 'net that isn't in root position!

And that's where it gets easier. By actually making it a root chord, in other words barring the lot on fret 9, you'll move your fingers up a little, which will stop the ring finger muting the 3rd string. Of course, you don't *have* to play the bottom string, but without that sounding, it's going to be C♯6/G♯.

Comment: Funny answer.  I personally don't like these partial bars that require concave finger shapes.  But they are valid, and important. +1

Comment: @ggcg - no need to turn inside out with my suggestion! But sometimes, it's needed - two finger A-shape barres come to mind, to give relief to the top string. Also for my 13th shape.

Comment: I routinely use the classical guitar A bar shape with two stings barred with the index and the second on the C#.  That one doesn't bother me.  I do have psoriatic arthritis and too much baring in that manner aggravates it.  PsA really only affects the small finger joints.  I would not suggest that it is an invalid technique, just that at this point in my life I've moved away from them.  I will try your fingering but I suspect it will induce some concavity in my hand.

Comment: @ggcg: I also play classical guitar, and have similar problems (arthritis). But even without that, this fingering just isn't possible for me, and never was. My fingers won't do it. I'd be inclined to either drop the lowest g# or c#, depending on the rest. Or maybe move the lowest c# an octave down.

Comment: There is a Jazz guitarist on the east coast named David Stryker.  He's really good.  I've seen him live a few times and even jammed with him at an open mic.  He often plays quick solo lines with 2 and maybe 3 voice harmonies by rapidly flattening his fingers.  It makes me squirm to watch.  It sounds cool and he's great, but for me it's like watching someone get kicked in the... you know what.